# Tables and results - How to write a If statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, error-handling

I need to filter a table (as and object) and copy the results in a specific range. Sometimes I get data from the table and sometimes not. When I get data it's ok, I copy paste the visible data on specific range, but when I don't get data it paste the whole column which it's wrong.
I want, that when there is no data visible in the table go to the next step.

I tried this:

```
Dim Table as ListObject
Set Table = Thisworkbook.ListObjects("Table")


Table.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="Lunes", Operator:=xlAnd
Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Range("Tema1Lun").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="=*TV*", Operator:=xlAnd
        If Table.DataBodyRange = 0 Then
                GoTo Filter2
        ElseIf Range("Table[Column1]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            With Range("Table[Column2]:Table[Column3]").Copy
            End With
                Range("SpecificRange").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
       End If
                
        
Filter2:
Table.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="Lunes", Operator:=xlAnd
Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Range("Tema1Lun").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: `If Table.DataBodyRange = 0 Then` what is this testing for exactly?

Comment: DataBodyRange is a range object, think of it as a pointer to a rectangular set of cells in your sheet.   The DataBodyRange itself will not be zero, the rows inside it will count to zero.  Try Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count instead.  Not sure if this works or if Table.DataBodyRange Is Null is the test you want.

Comment: Filtering the table does not affect the row count returned by `Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`. To check if there is visible data in the `DataBodyRange` after filtering, you can use `ListColumns(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it!
I used this:

```js
If Range("Table[Column1]").RowHeight = 0 Then
     GoTo Filter2
 ElseIf Range("Table[Column1]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count >= 1 Then
     With Range("Table[Column2]:Table[Column3]").Copy
     End With
          Range("rng_HLLun1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          Application.CutCopyMode = False End If

Filter2:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `On Error Resume Next` to check if there are any visible rows.

```vb
    Dim rng As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table")
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="Lunes", Operator:=xlAnd
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Sheets(1).Range("Tema1Lun").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="=*TV*", Operator:=xlAnd
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("Table[Column1]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Filter2
    Else
        Range("Table[Column2]:Table[Column3]").Copy
        Range("SpecificRange").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is close to working. However, using `If Table.DataBodyRange = 0` as a condition to check for no visible data in the table will not work as intended.

> DataBodyRange property returns a **Range** object that represents the range of values in a Table. (Note: It regardless of any filtering.)

> https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.databodyrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461

```
    Dim Table as ListObject
    Set Table = Thisworkbook.ListObjects("Table")

    If Table.ListColumns(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        GoTo Filter2
    Else
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("Table[Column2]:Table[Column3]").Copy
        Range("SpecificRange").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `ListObject.DataBodyRange` here, not `PivotTable`

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. You are right. It is a auto-complete typo when I type in my text editor.